# Showing that the set of all finite binary strings is countable via Cantor-Bernstein-Schroder

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Suppose that $A$ is the set of all finite binary strings. We need to show an injection  $A \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$.

1. $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$

Each number in the decimal system has its own unique representation in the binary system, which makes this an injective function.

2. $A \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$

We first put a "1" at the beginning of every binary string, so that for example $0001$ becomes $10001$. This is to avoid $0001$ and $001$ being mapped to the same element. Then, we convert the number in the binary system to the decimal system.

**My question is:** Even though I intuitively know that each number in the decimal system has its own unique representation in the binary system, since I don't have an explicit $f(n)= ..., n \in \mathbb{N}$ formula, I don't know how to prove it. Do I need to prove it further, or is what I said above sufficient?

The same goes for the second injective function. Intuitively, it seems fine, but since I don't have an explicit formula I don't know how to show injectivity.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Note that $\Bbb N$ is defined as numbers, not decimal representations.  Each number has a binary representation, so there is no need to go through decimal.  I think the statement that each number has a unique decimal or binary representation is simple enough you don't need to justify it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this alternate proof.

Map each binary sequence $b=(a_1, a_2,..., a_n)$ where the $a_i$ are the digits from right to left, as in that $a_1$ is the first digit from the right $a_2$ the second and so on to the natural number $$N(b) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i^{a_i}$$
Where $p_i$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ smallest prime. It should be easy to see that this is an injection of $A$ into $\mathbb N$.

This shows that $A$ has the same cardinality as some subset of $\mathbb N$. Realizing that every infinite subset of $\mathbb N$ has the same cardinality as that of $\mathbb N$ and proving that $A$ is infinite will complete the proof.

Although this is different from the proof you are proposing, I hope it is still of help as this one only constructs 1 injection (saving you the trouble of having to come up with a second) and even that with an explicit formula.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I see the product of primes being often used but I'm afraid I'm not sure how this ensures uniqueness in the set $\mathbb{N}$. For example, for the number $1011$ we use $2^1 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^0 \cdot 7^1$. 

Why do we use primes? Why do we use a product (and not a sum)? Couldn't we just have used $\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i$, without exponentiation?

Comment: It boils down to the fact that every natural number has a unique prime factorisation and that no two of them have the same prime factorisation. Since this maps each binary sequence to a distinct product of primes, no two binary sequences will map to the same natural number. If exponentiation was left out, all binary sequences of a given length, say 2, would map to the same natural number. If a sum of primes is used, we can't use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic as we do here.